# d3 force graph: sticky nodes

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I would like to add a behavior to a force directed graph layout in D3 in such a way that once dropped, a dragged-and-dropped svg node sticks in its place, no longer changing position no matter what else happens in the graph. I have done some reading about this API but I can't figure out a way to get that one working.

The problem I am trying to solve is allowing a user to "pick apart" a complex force graph.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `fixed` property of the node to true on mousedown.

```
node.on("mousedown", function(d) { d.fixed = true; });
```

For example: http://bl.ocks.org/3750558

Comment: In the example, once a node was clicked and dragged, it remained permanently highlighted and sticky. Is it possible to click it again to release it from its "stickiness"?

Comment: Sure, you could set `d.fixed = false` on dblclick, for example.

Comment: node.on('dblclick', function(d){ d.fixed = false; })

Comment: Dear Sir, you have solved my headache with this example :)