# D3 - partly force directed graph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, force-layout

As I'm a beginner, here's another question about D3.js.

I have constructed a force directed graph, just as a lot did.

All the nodes are stored in one array and all links in another.

Now I want the central node to be fixed in the middle of the svg and the others lingering around it.

Is there any possibility to cut only one node out of the force layout without it falling out of my net? Has anybody already made it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `fixed` property of a node to `true`, then place it where you like - see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496851/d3-force-graph-sticky-nodes).

```
// explicity set node position
var fixedNode = graph.nodes[0];
fixedNode.fixed = true;
fixedNode.x = width/2;
fixedNode.y = height/2;
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/z2cye/